# Qual a diferença entre o Statement e o PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, conexão

Quando paguei a cadeira de banco de dados, trabalhamos só com o banco, isoladamente sem nenhuma ligação com uma aplicação que interagisse externamente com o SGBD.
Só depois nos foi apresentado o JDBC(Java Database Connectivity). Mas devido a correria do curso aprendi do JDBC só o necessário para lidar com o banco de dados.

Portanto tenho a seguinte duvida:

Qual a difrença entre  o  Statement e  o PreparedStatement e quando devo usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A diferença vai além da simples adição de parâmetros.

A maioria dos bancos de dados relacionais lida com uma consulta (*query*) JDBC / SQL em quatro passos:

1. Interpretar (*parse*) a consulta SQL;
2. Compilar a consulta SQL;
3. Planejar e otimizar o caminho de busca dos dados;
4. Executar a consulta otimizada, buscando e retornando os dados.

Um *Statement* irá sempre passar pelos quatro passos acima para cada consulta SQL enviada para o banco.

Já um *Prepared Statement* pré-executa os passos (1) a (3). Então, ao criar um *Prepared Statement* alguma pré-otimização é feita de imediato. O efeito disso é que, se você pretende executar a mesma consulta repetidas vezes mudando apenas os parâmetros de cada uma, a execução usando *Prepared Statements* será mais rápida e com menos carga sobre o banco.

Outra vantagem dos *Prepared Statements* é que, se utilizados corretamente, ajudam a evitar ataques de Injeção de SQL. **Note que para isso** é preciso que os parâmetros da consulta sejam atribuídos através dos métodos `setInt()`, `setString()`, etc. presentes na interface `PreparedStatement` e não por concatenação de strings.

Para uma consulta que não requer nenhum parâmetro e que vai ser executada poucas vezes, um `Statement` basta. Para os demais casos, prefira `PreparedStatement`.

(Baseado [nesta resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271249/difference-between-statement-and-preparedstatement) e em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 12):

A diferença entre elas é que você pode usar `Statement` quando você pretende executar instruções SQL fixas, ou seja instruções de texto puro, como as seguinte:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM sua_tabela WHERE col1 = 'value1' AND col3 = 1");
```

E quando você pretende executar instruções SQL parametrizadas como a seguinte abaixo, você deve usar `PreparedStatement`, que também possibilita que você especifique o tipo do parâmetro passado como `Int`, `String`, `Float` etc, também fornecendo uma maior segurança na integridade de dados passado para execução no banco de dados, pois evita que você passe dados invalidos na instrução sql:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.preparedStatement("SELECT col1, col2 FROM sua_tabela WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?");
stmt.setString(1, "value1");
stmt.setInt(2, 1);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 9):

`PreparedStatement` é uma interface mais especializada de `Statement`, logo, lhe permite maior flexibilidade ao interagir com o SGBD. Com um objeto do tipo `Statement`, por exemplo, você pode enviar uma SQL para o SGBD fazer o processamento, porém sua SQL já tem que estar "pronta", com os valores embutidos nela.

Já com um objeto `PreparedStatement`, você pode parametrizar os valores em sua SQL. Exemplo:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.preparedStatement("select * from tabela where id = ?");

stmt.setInt(1,99);
```

O fato é que você pode usar os dois, porém como dito, o `PreparedStatement` lhe fornece maior flexibilidade.