# Pesquisar em uma tabela no MySQL com o Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar buscar alguma coisa na tabela, sou novato então fiz do jeito que sei.

Código do botão:

```
livros.setPesquisarLivro(txtLivro.getText());
    try {
        modelo.setNumRows(0);

        for (ObjetoLivro c : livroDAO.pesquisarLivro(livros)) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                c.getNomeLivro(),
                c.getAutor(),
                c.getGenero()});
                c.getAlunoLivro();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Código da pesquisa:

```
public ArrayList<ObjetoLivro> pesquisarLivro(ObjetoLivro pesquisar) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = ConnectionFactory.getStatement().executeQuery("SELECT IDLIVRO,NOMELIVRO,AUTOR,GENERO,NOMEALUNO FROM LIVRO WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE  '%"+pesquisar+"%'");
    ArrayList<ObjetoLivro> livros = new ArrayList<ObjetoLivro>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        ObjetoLivro livros2 = new ObjetoLivro();
        livros2.setIdLivro(rs.getInt(1));
        livros2.setNomeLivro(rs.getString(2));
        livros2.setAutor(rs.getString(3));
        livros2.setGenero(rs.getString(4));
        livros2.setAlunoLivro(rs.getString(5));
        livros.add(livros2);
    }
    return livros;
}
```

Código do `ConnectionFactory`:

```
package util;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ConnectionFactory {

private static Connection connection = null;
private static Statement statement;

static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteca",
                 "root", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static Statement getStatement() {
    return statement;
}
}
```

Código do `ObjetoLivro`:

```
package Model;
public class ObjetoLivro {
private String nomeLivro,autor,genero,alunoLivro,pesquisarLivro;
private int idLivro;
public String getPesquisarLivro() {
    return pesquisarLivro;
}

public void setPesquisarLivro(String pesquisarLivro) {
    this.pesquisarLivro = pesquisarLivro;
}

public String getNomeLivro() {
    return nomeLivro;
}

public void setNomeLivro(String nomeLivro) {
    this.nomeLivro = nomeLivro;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

public int getIdLivro() {
    return idLivro;
}

public void setIdLivro(int idLivro) {
    this.idLivro = idLivro;
}

public String getAlunoLivro() {
    return alunoLivro;
}

public void setAlunoLivro(String alunoLivro) {
    this.alunoLivro = alunoLivro;
} 
}
```

O retorno do código da pesquisa é:

> []

E a minha tabela não mostra nada, depois de clicar no botão de pesquisar.

Comment: O que é `modelo.setNumRows(0);`? Por que você chama `livroDAO.pesquisarLivro(livros);` duas vezes?

Comment: Você está pesquisando direto no banco ne? Você precisa informar todos os campos do objetolivro na query, pois o java não tem como saber quais campos este objeto possui e nem qual  está relacionado com as colunas da tabela.

Comment: Mostre o código das classes `ConnectionFactory` e `ObjetoLivro`.

Comment: O modelo.setNumRows(0), serve para começar a tabela na coluna 0, pois minha tabela foi configurada manualmente.

Comment: O problema é justamente o que eu havia comentado, você está mandando um objetolivro para a query, mas o java não sabe o que pesquisar, você deve informar qual campo de objetolivro quer que seja alvo da pesquisa na query.

Comment: Query correta: `"SELECT IDLIVRO,NOMELIVRO,AUTOR,GENERO,NOMEALUNO FROM LIVRO WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE  '%"+ pesquisar.getNomeLivro() +"%'"`

Comment: Leia isso: [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Comment: Ah, não é só porque você vai colocar os resultados em uma `JTable` que a sua dúvida seja sobre `JTable` ou dependa de conhecimentos intrínsecos a `JTable`. De fato, a sua dúvida é em relação ao JDBC e você não tem problema nenhum com a sua `JTable` no escopo dessa questão. Assim sendo, tirei (novamente) a tag do [jtable] e acrescentei a tag do [jdbc].

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que, no trecho abaixo, você está concatenando a própria instância da classe `ObjetoLivro` ao invés do nome do livro:

```
WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE '%"+pesquisar+"%'");
//Deveria ser
WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE '%"+pesquisar.getNomeLivro()+"%'");
```

Além disso, o ideal seria você utilizar um `PreparedStatement` ao invés de um `Statement`, já que o primeiro tem vantages sobre o segundo como você pode ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99620/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-statement-e-o-preparedstatement).

Com um `PreparedStatement` seu código ficaria assim:

ConnectionFactory:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    //O resto do código

    public static PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
        connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

Código da pesquisa:

```
public ArrayList<ObjetoLivro> pesquisarLivro(ObjetoLivro pesquisar) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = ConnectionFactory.createPreparedStatement("SELECT IDLIVRO,NOMELIVRO,AUTOR,GENERO,NOMEALUNO FROM LIVRO WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE ?");
    ps.setString(1, "%" + pesquisar.getNomeLivro() + "%");

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<ObjetoLivro> livros = new ArrayList<ObjetoLivro>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        ObjetoLivro livro = new ObjetoLivro();
        livro.setIdLivro(rs.getInt(1));
        livro.setNomeLivro(rs.getString(2));
        livro.setAutor(rs.getString(3));
        livro.setGenero(rs.getString(4));
        livro.setAlunoLivro(rs.getString(5));
        livros.add(livro);
    }
    return livros;
}
```

Comment: Seu método não funcionou totalmente, pois mesmo que eu clique em pesquisar ele fica sem nada de busca, porém parou de aparecer o [] de retorno.

Comment: @MarcosKropp A consulta feita é case-sensitive. A string que você usa na pesquisa está no mesmo case da string no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim estou testando tudo em letra minúscula, creio eu que a pesquisa não esteja aparecendo em função do método de pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro problema do seu código, como outros já apontaram é isso:

```
'%"+pesquisar+"%'"
```

O que você queria era isso:

```
'%"+pesquisar.getNomeLivro()+"%'"
```

Uma outra possibilidade é trocar isso:

```
public ArrayList<ObjetoLivro> pesquisarLivro(ObjetoLivro pesquisar) throws SQLException {
```

Por isso:

```
public List<ObjetoLivro> pesquisarLivro(String pesquisar) throws SQLException {
```

Isso é porque acredito que você queira um método que:

> "*a partir de um título ou parte de um título de livro a pesquisar, retorne todos os livros que tenham esse título*".

Isso é um pouco diferente de um método que:

> "*a partir de um livro que tenha algum título, retorne todos os livros que contenham o título do livro fornecido dentro de seus próprios títulos*".

Entretanto o seu código ainda tem outros problemas:

- Você deveria estar usando o *try-with-resources*. Para entender o porquê e como usá-lo, veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132).
- O seu código tem um problema de [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Para solucionar esses problemas, eis como ficam a sua `ConnectionFactory` e o seu método de pesquisa:

```java
package util;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    public static Connection connect() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteca", "root", "");
    }
}
```

```java
public List<ObjetoLivro> pesquisarLivro(String nomeLivro) throws SQLException {
    List<ObjetoLivro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT IDLIVRO, NOMELIVRO, AUTOR, GENERO, NOMEALUNO FROM LIVRO WHERE NOMELIVRO LIKE ?";
    try (
        Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.connect();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, "%" + nomeLivro + "%");
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                ObjetoLivro livros2 = new ObjetoLivro();
                livros2.setIdLivro(rs.getInt(1));
                livros2.setNomeLivro(rs.getString(2));
                livros2.setAutor(rs.getString(3));
                livros2.setGenero(rs.getString(4));
                livros2.setAlunoLivro(rs.getString(5));
                livros.add(livros2);
            }
        }
    }
    return livros;
}
```

Comment: Victor Stafusa seu método também não funcionou, pois ocorre um erro no setParameter em que não sei como corrigir.

Comment: @MarcosKropp Editei a resposta e corrigi. Foi uma confusão que fiz com o nome do método.

Comment: Novamente não fucionou, pois com esse ConnectionFactory ocoore diversos erros.

Comment: @MarcosKropp Que erros? São erros de compilação ou `SQLException`s? Poderia postar a(s) mensagem(ns) de erro inteira(s)?

Comment: O software manda eu adicionar bibliotecas de importação, mas quando puxo ele não me deixa compilar sem erro.

Comment: @MarcosKropp Isso daí sugere que o seu problema então é alguma outra coisa que não está relacionada a esta pergunta. Neste caso, sugiro fazer uma nova pergunta e nela perguntar sobre esses erros de importação de bibliotecas.