# Como extrair String de uma consulta ao banco de dados?

Tags: java, postgresql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou implementando uma tela de consulta, o usuário terá que informar o nome e após os campos abaixo terão que ser preenchidos. Minha dúvida é como realizar a consulta?
Tentei fazer por Select assim :

```
 private void consultarBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(nomeTxt.getText().equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Informe o nome para realizar a consulta!");
        }
        else
        {
          
             try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Connection conexao= new bancoDeDados().getConnection();
            Statement estado = conexao.createStatement();
              String sql= "select * from inquilinos where nome='"+nomeTxt.getText()+"';";
              
              
            PreparedStatement statement= conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            
            statement.execute();
            cpfTxt.setText(sql);
            conexao.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CadastroDeUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
             
             
         }
        
    }
```

Queria ver com vocês como fazer e como substituir essa parte ´

> cpfTxt.setText(sql);´

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas enfim: não concatene os campos diretamente na query, pois isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a ataques de [SQL injection](/q/100729/112052). Em vez disso, prefira setar os valores no `PreparedStatement`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99625/112052

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o código ficou assim (tem que usar o resultset) :

.
.
.

```
Connection conexao= new bancoDeDados().getConnection();
            
              String sql= "select * from inquilinos where nome='"+nomeTxt.getText()+"';";
              
              
            PreparedStatement statement= conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
```

.
.
.